# How to limit Swagger to only serve one resource documentation

Tags: java, guice, swagger

I would like to limit swagger to only generate documentation for one resource instead of scanning the whole package. I am using jersey 1.16, guice and swagger 1.5. this is my configuration:

```
BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http","https"});
beanConfig.setHost("http://localhost:7070");
beanConfig.setBasePath("/rest");
beanConfig.setResourcePackage(SessionReportingResource.class.getPackage().getName());
beanConfig.setScan(true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: A bit of a bad answer, but can't you just subpackage the ones you want to be parsed by swagger?

Comment: Thanks that would be possible. However I wonder if there is a different way